# Convert an Array column to Array of Structs in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, struct, pyspark

I have a Dataframe containing 3 columns

```
| str1      | array_of_str1        | array_of_str2  |
+-----------+----------------------+----------------+
| John      | [Size, Color]        | [M, Black]     |
| Tom       | [Size, Color]        | [L, White]     |
| Matteo    | [Size, Color]        | [M, Red]       |
```

I want to add the Array column that contains the 3 columns in a struct type

```
| str1      | array_of_str1        | array_of_str2  | concat_result                                 |
+-----------+----------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| John      | [Size, Color]        | [M, Black]     | [[[John, Size , M], [John, Color, Black]]]    |
| Tom       | [Size, Color]        | [L, White]     | [[[Tom, Size , L], [Tom, Color, White]]]      |
| Matteo    | [Size, Color]        | [M, Red]       | [[[Matteo, Size , M], [Matteo, Color, Red]]]  |
```

Comment: can you provide schama of dataframe

Comment: |-- AdditionalAttribute: array (nullable = true) | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) | | | |-- str1: string (nullable = true) | | | |-- array_of_str1: string (nullable = true) | | | |-- array_of_str2: string (nullable = true)

Comment: @lazycoder, what is `AdditionalAttribute`, is this a field-name of the column `concat_result`? is your spark 2.4+ or below?

Comment: @jxc AdditionalAttribute is the array name. I'm using Spark 2.4.3

Comment: @lazycoder, so `AdditionalAttribute` is your desired column name, not `concat_result` shown in your post? and the new column has a schema of array of structs with 3 string fields?

Comment: I was passing by and wondering if you had found the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @Oli Yes i did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the number of elements in the arrays in fixed, it is quite straightforward using the `array` and `struct` functions. Here is a bit of code in scala.

```scala
val result = df
    .withColumn("concat_result", array((0 to 1).map(i => struct(
                     col("str1"),
                     col("array_of_str1").getItem(i),
                     col("array_of_str2").getItem(i)
    )) : _*))
```

And in python, since you were asking about pyspark:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("concat_result", F.array(*[ F.struct(
                  F.col("str1"),
                  F.col("array_of_str1").getItem(i),
                  F.col("array_of_str2").getItem(i))
              for i in range(2)]))
```

And you get the following schema:

```
root
 |-- str1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- array_of_str1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- array_of_str2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- concat_result: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- str1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what if the size of the array_of_str1 and array_of_str2 is variable. How can i dynamically specify the range here

Answer (score 0):

### Spark >= 2.4.x

For dynamically values you can use [high-order functions](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

expr = "TRANSFORM(arrays_zip(array_of_str1, array_of_str2), x -> struct(str1, concat(x.array_of_str1), concat(x.array_of_str2)))"
df = df.withColumn('concat_result', f.expr(expr))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Schema and output:

```
root
 |-- array_of_str1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- array_of_str2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- str1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- concat_result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- str1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col3: string (nullable = true)

+-------------+-------------+------+-----------------------------------------+
|array_of_str1|array_of_str2|str1  |concat_result                            |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----------------------------------------+
|[Size, Color]|[M, Black]   |John  |[[John, Size, M], [John, Color, Black]]  |
|[Size, Color]|[L, White]   |Tom   |[[Tom, Size, L], [Tom, Color, White]]    |
|[Size, Color]|[M, Red]     |Matteo|[[Matteo, Size, M], [Matteo, Color, Red]]|
+-------------+-------------+------+-----------------------------------------+
```